# How to set connection string to MySQL database for ASP.NET tableadapter

Tags: mysql, asp.net, dataset, connection-string, tableadapter

I have 2 connectionstrings in my Web.config file. When I however add a new tableadapter on a new dataset, I can't select the `conn_wp` connectionstring from the `Connection` property dropdown. The credentials for the `conn_wp` connection are correct, I tested them in MySQL Workbench.

I see these options under `Connection` property for the tableadapter

- conn1 (Web.config)
- (New Connection...)
- (None)

But no `conn_wp` option..also I can't type myself in this field.

**Web.config**

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="conn1" connectionString="data source=(local)\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=mydb;User Id=myuser;Password=Mypwd;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="conn_wp" connectionString="Server=localhost;Database=wpblog;Uid=myuser;Pwd=mypwd;Convert Zero Datetime=True" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

I already installed the right connector and have included the resulting `MySql.Data.dll` into my project, but get this error too:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to download [MySql Connector](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/) and add reference of it to your project.

Your connection string has no issue.

Comment: Thank you. I've updated my question with an additional test, since the problem is not solved yet.

Comment: check this link it may help https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/08a48cad-619d-4421-b584-f2b5550ba6c5/dataset-designer-unable-to-find-connection-myconn-mysettings1-for-object-mysettings?forum=winformsdatacontrols